# Binding an IP address to a container port on docker for windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm new to docker. I've been able to create a custom version of the Jenkins CI server, storing its data on windows quite successfully. In fact, it was very easy and quick.

Now that I'm done testing and everything is configured on my test machine, I'd like to run the container against a different IP address than its host. I'm using Docker for Windows, running under HyperV. The old world I'm coming from had a VM that was dedicated to Jenkins, and it had a static IP, and exposed port 8080 for the web interface. Can i configure docker on windows to do the same thing?

I tried, for example, on my test machine at home:

```
PS C:\Users\Gordon> docker run -p 192.168.1.25:8080:8080 -p 192.168.1.25:50000:50000 -v C:\Users\Gordon\Documents\JenkinsData:/var/jenkins_home --name my_jenkins --restart always jenkins
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my_jenkins (22fa57b3a6af26246231e599e9e0bda7c86641f340a4b6a64cb1659b39b7bdba): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.1.25:50000: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

Despite it not quite doing what I wanted (I think), I tried adding 192.168.1.25 as an "alternate ip" address to my adaptor, but that didn't work - I got the same error.

Any ideas? Since VM's are allowed to have static IP addresses, I figure this must be possible.